# React Native - What should be the redirect url for instagram integration using react-native-instagram-login

Tags: react-native, instagram, react-native-instagram-login

I am using react-native-instagram-login for instagram integration in react native.
I have tried but when i am login in instagram then it is giving me this error

`{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}`

Here is my code

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.instagramLogin.show()}>
   <Text style={{color: 'black', textAlign: 'center'}}>Login now</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<InstagramLogin
   ref={(ref) => (this.instagramLogin = ref)}
   appId="*******"
   appSecret="**********"
   redirectUrl="https://www.google.com"
   scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']}
   onLoginSuccess={(data) => console.log('check data ', data)}
   onLoginFailure={(data) => console.log(data)}
/>
```

and in developer facebook i have putted Valid OAuth Redirect URIs - https://www.google.com

Comment: Now it works. I had added https://www.google.com previously in my code and hence it was not working. later i came to know that facebook dev console on saving redirect url appends "/" at the end. So now in redirectUrl i am passing https://www.google.com/ with a slash and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just simple you have to add trail slash on redirect url.

```js
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.instagramLogin.show()}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', textAlign: 'center'}}>Login now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <InstagramLogin
          ref={(ref) => (this.instagramLogin = ref)}
          appId="*******"
          appSecret="**********"
          redirectUrl="https://www.google.com/"
          scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']}
          onLoginSuccess={(data) => console.log('check data ', data)}
          onLoginFailure={(data) => console.log(data)}
        />
```